# Canvas. Single finger draw. if click on button line color must change

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have 2classes DrawLine.class  where the line is drawn and Main.class where the xml file is called in which the buttons and the view element are registered. I need that at the click of a button I can draw a certain color. For example, the button "blue" when it is pressed the line becomes blue, etc. Tried to implement as it is specified in DrawLine.class but an error in the logs points to the string setContentView (R.layout.activity_main); In general, it is not so important where the mistake is made, how to implement the method of rendering the color by pressing the button.
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnW10"
            android:text="Width10"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnW40"
            android:text="Width40"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnW70"
            android:text="Width70"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnBlue"
            android:text="Blue"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnRed"
            android:text="Red"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnGreen"
            android:text="Green"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.vladislav.canvaswc.DrawLine
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

DrawLine.class

```
public class DrawLine extends View implements View.OnClickListener
{

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    float width=5f;
    int color;
   //

   // btnB.OnClickListener(this);

    public DrawLine(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init(context);

    }
    public DrawLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
        Button btnB=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
        btnB.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnBlue: color=Color.BLUE; break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a method to change paint instance inside DrawLine class and invoke it from the onClick method of the button

```
public void changeColor(int color) {
    paint.setColor(color);
}
```

Comment: Your answer did not help me, but I tried to do it. Maybe I misunderstood you

Comment: Necessary thing to change drawing color dynamically is to change color of the paint object. Change paint object's color where you add listener to buttons.

Comment: As far i see from your code, your onClick method is invoked when you touch the DrawLine instance. Create a setOnClickListener for button and inside that method change paint object's color

Comment: public void init(Context context) {

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
        Button btnB=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
        btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnBlue: paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); break;
        }
            }
        });
    }

Comment: I have mistake in compilation :C pls change my code. This will be more visible

Comment: You should get instance of buttons and set listeners inside `onCreate()` method of your  Activity

Comment: Then I must create an instance of the DrawLine.class in onCreate?
DrawLine dr= new DrawLine()?
and in Onclick write  switch(view.getId())
                {
                    case R.id.btnBlue:  dr.changeColor();break;
                }

Comment: No you should get it using `findViewById(id_inside_xml_file)`, if you do it with `new` you create a new instance and you will have to add it to your LinearLayout but you don't want that.

Set an id for your DrawLine inside xml and inflate it then invoke the method i wrote you when a button is clicked.

Comment: Yes. working:) but if i draw line default color is black, i click button"blue" and my first and second line is blue. but first must be black(default) and second blue. Why 2 lines blue?

Comment: It's because you are still drawing the same Path instance. Paint instance draws path instance in color you set paint instance to.

Comment: as fix this bag?